# uploaded photo in ui image viewer keep disappears

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can upload a photo into ui image viewer from camera roll but when I restart my app or go to another page and come back, the uploaded photo disappears. How do I keep them?

```
 - (IBAction)selectImage:(id)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
UIImage *chosenImage = selectedImage;

self.homeImage.image = chosenImage;
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage.images);
NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myImage.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
```

I expect the second method to keep the image in the internal database and keep showing my uploaded image, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes second method where you writeToFile is saving into the app sandbox, but after you terminate the app, you never load it back! To load back the image when app restarted, you need to load it with imageWithContentsofFile in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the image from file and assign it to your view after view is created, something similar to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString * imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myImage.png"];
    self.homeImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
}
```

Comment: Hi the photo disappears when I permanently close (from the app switcher) the app and restart it. How do I keep it?